# When I Google for my real name, my Stack Overflow profile shows up as a popular result even though my profile does not contain my name...why?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, display-names, privacy

This could be entirely a Google issue, but I'm curious if it's anything that StackOverflow is doing.  For personal reasons, I'm trying to make it so accounts of mine do not show up when a user Google searches for my real name.  My Stack Overflow profile is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/159658/sgusc

It displays no real information about me, yet if I Google search for my real name, this profile page still shows up as the second search result.

The change to username "sgusc" is fairly recent (on the order of a couple months).  My old username was actually just my real name and I suspect that has something to do with it.

Thoughts?

Comment: As an addendum, I just realized that my MetaSO and SuperUser profiles were still my real name, while SO and ServerFault were "sgusc".  That may also be related.

Comment: @Bobby: Yeah, I was assuming that would be the case, but I figured it doesn't hurt to ask.  Strangely enough, the cached Google page doesn't have my real name on it either.

Comment: This is indeed weird - the cached page doesn't have your real name anywhere, not even in the source code. This is either a Google caching issue, or a mild form of Google Bombing, i.e. somewhere a page with an extremely high page rank pointing to your profile with your real name as the text

Comment: @sgusc: See my answer, also, you need to change your username on all associated SE sites. ;)

Comment: @Pekka - I don't think it's simply caching (see my answer).  Google learns what words/ids/URLs are strongly associated and keeps them around, presumably until it decides it needs to unlearn them.  The user's page has *several* identifying factors that will always be the same, therefore making a permanently link with previous search terms found very strongly (only?) on the profile page.

Comment: @Pekka Bah.  Thanks.  Missed that one.

Comment: @Renesis yeah, that is what I mean by Google Bombing (Remember "Miserable Failure"?)

Comment: @Pekka - you're right, this is definitely an effect of the same conceptual linking system.

Comment: So as an interesting side note, Google recently launched a dashboard for helping manage online identity:  https://www.google.com/dashboard/

Answer (score 21):

Look at the top of the cached page:

[image: Google Cache Result]

There are still old links to your profile page floating around.

Comment: Haha.  Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 10):

One of the main factors that may still be linking your real name to your new user page (new since the username slug is a part of the URL) could be **Google's automatic synonym searching**.

As [Bobby pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89975/when-i-google-for-my-real-name-my-stack-overflow-profile-shows-up-as-a-popular-r/89978#89978), the cache believes "these terms only appear in links pointing to this page".  However, I've tested that out before and I don't believe that's the whole story.  It actually seems to be Google's canned message for *any* terms that were only indirectly related to the results page, **including but not limited to** links pointing to the page.

As seen from [this announcement on the Google blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2008/07/technologies-behind-google-ranking.html), **Google has started executing searches based on related words automatically:**

> Understanding queries: It is critical that we understand what our users are looking for (beyond just the few words in their query). **We have made several notable advances in this area including a best-in-class spelling suggestion system, an advanced synonyms system, and a very strong concept analysis system.**

This synonym searching is both dynamic and contextual, in that it learns as it crawls, and relates terms based on the context they are found in.

So the fact that you recently changed your username probably means that Google has a fairly good guess that **Your Real Name** is strongly associated with **sgusc** or with your ID (in the URL, which didn't change) or possibly even multiple data points on the page (many links which have only ever appeared to Google on *your* page — your specific questions and answers, for example, since each link includes the ID of the post you actually made, not just the whole question ID).

Comment: Interesting thought.  I wonder if there's a good way to break that association or if another username change might do it.  I'll play around and get back to you.

Comment: Good detailed answer, +1 @sgusc I assume this will probably go away automatically over time - "probably" because I'm not sure about your name that will be in the old profile links... But I can't imagine them having that much effect

Comment: Actually, I think there's even more to it than this.  In the past, my name erroneously appeared in a news article that had nothing to do with me; Google of course picked up and indexed the article and searches upon my name returned that page.  I quickly contacted the media outlet and had my name removed; I also requested that Google remove my name from its index of the page.  However, even though nothing else in the page has anything to do with me and nothing else in Google's index links to that particular page, searches on my name continue to bring it up as a result. Quite disturbing, really.